# Is it possible to wrap HTML content into DIV or something else and do not break page layout?

Tags: html

Document contains some HTML elements. Some elements I need to wrap into DIV (or any other HTML element) so that document's layout should still valid. Is it possible at all?

For example I have the following code:

```
<div style="float:left;">Left DIV</div>
<div style="float:right;">Right DIV</div>
```

I need to get something like this, so that document layout still valid and Right DIV is highlighted with dotted border:

```
<div style="float:left;">Left DIV</div>
<div class="wrapper" style="border:dotted 1px #666;">
    <div style="float:right;">Right DIV</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do that, your right div will no longer be floating, or at least its wrapper will not. You could either move the inline float style up to the wrapper, or you could simply get rid of the wrapper, and add the inline border style directly to the right div instead.

Does this help?

Try something like this:

```
<div style="float: left; border: 1px solid #000;">
   <div style="float: left;">Left DIV</div>
   <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
<div style="float: right; border: 1px solid #000;">
   <div style="float: right;">Right DIV</div>
   <br style="clear: both;" />
</div>
```

May want to test in older browsers to see if the layout holds up.

Comment: The inline float style doesn't display a dotted border, because its width and height is 0. Unfortunately I cannot modify right div. I should only wrap it.

Comment: why would the floating right div have a width and height of 0? It should be as large as whatever is contained inside of it, or you can set the width and height to whatever you want using styles.

Comment: oh i see you cannot edit it. well, you can wrap it within another floating div, and place an element below the inner div that has the style attribute "clear: both;", in order to give the wrapper a proper height, or you can just set the wrappers height and width using styles. i have edited my original post to show an example. keep in mind that the border will add two pixels worth of width to the right div, which may also throw off your layout depending.

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion works in case of right div, but if I need to wrap a left DIV now - this wrapper will broke layout :( And unfortunately I don't know whether inner DIV has float left or right. It should be possible to wrap any HTML element inside our DIV wrapper.

Comment: i edited it again for the left div. try this, and if it works, select the check mark next to my answer on the left. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

An HTML `<div>` certainly doesn't make your document layout invalid, but it may not display in the way that you want. If you don't like the fact that a `<div>` (by default) appears on its own line, you can set its `display` CSS attribute to `inline`:

```
<div style="display: inline;">
```

Otherwise you may want to consider using the `<span>` tag.

Comment: Yes, the div with inline style doesn't display a dotted border over the right div. The <span> tag has the same behavior and has empty size. Is the any other way to wrap right div and display border over it?